# emberjs on symfony2 dev enviroment dont work propertly

Tags: symfony, ember.js

I've builded a app with symfony2 the app expose an REST Api.

now i build a simple client for consuming

#### app.coffee -> app.js

```
App = Em.Application.create
    ready: ->
        @.entradas.load()
    Entrada: Em.Object.extend()
    entradas: Em.ArrayController.create
        content: []
        load: ->
            url = 'http://localhost/api/1/entrada'
            me = @
            $.ajax(
                url: url,
                method: 'GET',
                success: (data) ->
                    me.set('content', [])
                    for entrada in data.data.objects
                        me.pushObject DBPlus.Entrada.create(entrada)
            )
```

#### MyBundle:Home:index.html.twig

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" src="{{ asset('js/templates/entradas.hbs') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/libs/ember-1.0.pre.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

the problem here is when i run on `dev` enviroment and link the template like `<script type="text/x-handlebars" src="{{...}}">` the app dont work, nothing show but works fine over `prod` enviroment.

he only way that works on `dev` enviroment is inline template

#### MyBundle:Home:index.html.twig

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {% raw %}
    <ul class="entradas">
      {{#each App.entradas}}
        <li class="entrada">{{nombre}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
    {% endraw %}
</script>
```

### config_dev.yml

## Assetic Configuration

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
```

### can explain why this behavoir?

#### Note: I disabled the debug profiler toolbar, and nothing

Comment: When you say "dev env" or "prod env", do you mean the symfony env variable is changed on the same machine, or do you test on a dev machine and a prod machine?

Comment: can you show your assets setup for prod and dev? Do you use a controller in dev environment?

Comment: @Sgoettschkes you mean that what process use to compile Coffescript and Handlebars?

Comment: I mean the configuration for assetics in your config.yml/config_dev.yml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with rake-pipeline, I wrote a AssetFile with the following code:

```
output BUILD_DIR
input SRC_DIR do
  match '**/*.handlebars' do
    handlebars :precompile => true
    concat 'template.js'
  end
end
```

and in my `layout.html.twig` include

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/template.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which is the URL generated by this: {{ asset('js/templates/entradas.hbs') }} when on the dev environment? Does it work? As it is probably not working, which error do you get?

Comment: You misunderstood my problem, the problem is not the url itself. Is that when I embed the template works and when I link not, that is the problem. the URL are generated correctly

Comment: But you also said that embeding the template works when on the prod environment and not when on the development environment. So my concern is, what is generated by symfony when you access the embedded URL from the dev environment?

Comment: you're right. reading the documentation say the best is to embed templates. so I decided to change the strategy and I am attaching the templates in a .JS file

Comment: Please describe your solution as an answer and accept it, so if anyone has the same issue knows how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change twig Twig_Environment

```
    $this->options = array_merge(array(
        'tag_comment'     => array('{$', '$}'),
        'tag_block'       => array('{%', '%}'),
        'tag_variable'    => array('<%', '%>'),
        'whitespace_trim' => '-',
        'interpolation'   => array('${', '}'),
    ), $options);
```

**Path:\lib\Twig\Lexer.php**